# Question on an inequality concerning integrals.

Tags: lp-spaces, convolution, locally-compact-groups

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $f \in L^1(G).$ Define a linear map $L_f : L^2(G) \longrightarrow L^2(G)$ by $g \longmapsto f \ast g,\ $ $g \in L^2(G).$ Show that $L_f$ is bounded.

Here we need to show that $\|f \ast g\|_2 \leq C \|g\|_2$ for some $C \gt 0.$ It is not so inconsequent to expect that this constant has something to do with $\|f\|_2.$ But inspite of pondering over it for a long time I couldn't able to come up with the inequality I desired to. Could anyone give some suggestion in this regard which would enable me to lead to some progress? Any such cooperation will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch.

**EDIT** $:$ What I got is the following $:$

$$\|f \ast g\|_2 \leq \|g\|_2 \left (\int_G \int_G |f(t - s)|^2\ ds\ dt \right )^{\frac {1} {2}}.$$

Now what to do?

Comment: Aren't you done if you have that last inequality?

Comment: No I don't know whether the second integral term is finite or not.

Comment: Also what does $t-s$ mean in an arbitrary locally compact group? Do you mean $ts^{-1}$?

Comment: @QruantumSpace$:$ How do you know that $\|f\|_2 \lt \infty$ if $f \in L^1(G)\ $?

Comment: @Radbin Kumar Chakraborty See proposition 2.40 (a) in Folland's book "A course in abstract harmonic analysis".